# TFileStream Read() and Write() from and to c style byte/char buffer[]

Tags: c++builder

I just installed C++ Builder 12 and wanted to compile an ancient piece of software that uses a TFileStream to read and write to c style buffers.  For instance:

```cpp
DWORD MyFileStream::Read (BYTE *Buffer, DWORD Count)
{
try
    {
    if (File)
        return File->Read(Buffer, Count) ;
    }
catch(...)
    {
    LastError = GetLastError() ;
    return MY_ERROR_READ ;
    }
return 0x00 ;
}
```

This still compiles ok in 32 bit, but (going from c++ Builder 11.3 to 12) it now doesn't compile anymore in 64 bit.
So, after 20 years or so I had to go and have a look at TFileStream in the help file and it appears to solely use a DynamicArray ?

Confused ?
Why does it compile in 32 bit then ?
I have a feeling the help file is not complete ??
And more importantly, how do I fix this without creating a dynamic array (assuming that is still possible) ?

The error:

```
call to member function 'Read' is ambiguous
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1756, 36):  candidate function
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1771, 38):  candidate function
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1777, 36):  candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'BYTE *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to 'System::Sysutils::TBytes &' (aka 'DynamicArray<unsigned char> &') for 1st argument
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1779, 38):  candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'BYTE *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to 'System::Sysutils::TBytes &' (aka 'DynamicArray<unsigned char> &') for 1st argument
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1773, 36):  candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
[C++ Error] System.Classes.hpp(1775, 38):  candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
```

Comment: What does *it doesn't compile anymore* mean specifically? What errors are you getting (the complete, exact error message)? And try to cut back on the ?? marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, after 20 years or so I had to go and have a look at TFileStream in the help file and it appears to solely use a DynamicArray ?

That is incorrect. It still has overloads for working with raw buffers.

The real culprit is that `Read()` (and `Write()`) has additional overloads under 64-bit only, which are not documented yet but you would see them if you look at the declarations in `System.Classes.hpp`:

```cpp
public:
    virtual System::LongInt __fastcall Read(void *Buffer, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
    virtual System::LongInt __fastcall Write(const void *Buffer, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
#ifdef _WIN64
    virtual System::NativeInt __fastcall Read(void *Buffer, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
    virtual System::NativeInt __fastcall Write(const void *Buffer, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
#endif /* _WIN64 */
    virtual System::LongInt __fastcall Read(System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::LongInt Offset, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
    virtual System::LongInt __fastcall Write(const System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::LongInt Offset, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
#ifdef _WIN64
    virtual System::NativeInt __fastcall Read(System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::NativeInt Offset, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
    virtual System::NativeInt __fastcall Write(const System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::NativeInt Offset, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
#endif /* _WIN64 */
    System::LongInt __fastcall Read(System::Sysutils::TBytes &Buffer, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
    System::LongInt __fastcall Write(const System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::LongInt Count)/* overload */;
#ifdef _WIN64
    System::NativeInt __fastcall Read(System::Sysutils::TBytes &Buffer, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
    System::NativeInt __fastcall Write(const System::Sysutils::TBytes Buffer, System::NativeInt Count)/* overload */;
#endif /* _WIN64 */
```

This means that under 64-bit only, the 2-param `Read()` which you are trying to call now accepts both `LongInt` and `NativeInt` types for the buffer size, and since `DWORD` is implicitly convertible to both types, that is why your code is now ambiguous under 64-bit but not under 32-bit.

To solve this, you would need to explicitly tell the compiler which overload you want to call.  You can either:

- type-cast your `DWORD` to the desired integer type, eg:

```cpp
return File->Read(Buffer, static_cast<LongInt>(Count));
```

- or, you can cast the `Read` method itself to the desired overload type before calling it, eg:

```cpp
typedef LongInt __fastcall (__closure *TReadMethod)(void*, LongInt);
static_cast<TReadMethod>(stream->Read)(buffer, size);
```